# Deadlock mysql multiple batch update operations

Tags: mysql, sql-update, deadlock

I am getting following exception when I try to do a batch update. There are multiple threads running at same time which might be accessing a row in database. I am doing multiple batch updates. Can anyone please comment on relation between size of batch and deadlock ? By decreasing the batch size (currently batch size = 1000), will the probability of deadlock decrease ?

The exception I am getting is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: Do they update the same rows?

Comment: yes, that might be happening, I am filtering some rows in where clause though

Comment: If you're updating the same rows - that definitely might cause deadlocks.

Comment: I guess it might be innoDB too http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer*:

> yes, the probability would decrease

*Long answer*:

Lets figure out why the deadlocks are occurring. When you update a row an exclusive lock is set on this particular row and it will be held until your transaction is commited/rolled back. 
That means, no other transaction may update it — it would just block until the transaction is finished. A deadlock would occur when **tran1** is willing to lock rows being held by **tran2**, and **tran2**, in turn, is already waiting for some rows locked by **tran1**

Here's an example:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table a (id int primary key, value int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into a values (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql console 1:
step 1> start transaction;
step 3> update a set value = 1 where id = 2;
step 5> update a set value = 1 where id = 1;

mysql console 2:
step 2> start transaction;
step 4> update a set value = 1 where id = 1;
step 6> update a set value = 1 where id = 2;

ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The more rows are being touched(=updated) during every batch update, the higher the probability of such kind of conflicts is.

You might lower this probability by traversing the rows in a well-defined order. In this case the simple example I've provided wouldn't be feasible.
More details on avoiding deadlocks are in this awesome article:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/03/a-little-known-way-to-cause-a-database-deadlock/

Comment: link is deprecated :(